# How do I patch Berkeley DB 4.7.25 for use with OpenLDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

According to the OpenLDAP documentation, I'm supposed to patch Berkeley DB.

I've got Berkeley DB installed already, and I've found the patch files, but what do I do with them? They don't appear to be executable.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use patch command to apply patches to a source distribution and then recompile DB from sources

in a linux box you will need to do something like:

tar zxvf db-4.7.25.tar.gz

cd db-4.7.25

patch -p0 < patch.db-4.7.25.1

patch -p0 < patch.db-4.7.25.2

patch -p0 < patch.db-4.7.25.3

patch -p1 < patch.db-4.7.25.4

cd build_unix

../dist/configure

make

make install

Note that you should pass relevant options to configure, i not sure what are
requisites for OpenLDAP , but you are better asking in their forums

Regards,
José Gutíerrez de la Concha